# How to implement Comparable class

Tags: java, comparable

Ok I figured out how to make the GUI class and the sorting class but can seem to figure out how to implement the comparable class. I need to create rectangles of random sizes and then sort them out. Any help is appreciated thanks again.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;



public class TwoSorts extends Applet implements ActionListener

{
private final int APPLET_WIDTH = 600;
private final int APPLET_HEIGHT = 600;
Button sort;
Label sort_label;
String pr_name;
int[] random = new int[20];
int[] sorter = new int[20];


public void init()

{

    sort = new Button("Sort");
    add(sort);
    sort.addActionListener(this);
    sort_label = new Label("Orange Selection / Black Bubble");
    add(sort_label);
    randomGen(random);
    sorter = random; 
    setBackground (Color.white);
    setSize (APPLET_WIDTH, APPLET_HEIGHT); 
}  

private void randomGen (int...random) {


    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        random [i] = (int) (20 +(Math.random()*300-20));
        }
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ){


        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect((int) (10 + (i*50)), 300, 50, ((random[i])));
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect((int) (10 + (i*50)), 300, 25, (sorter[i]));
    }

    g.drawRect (20, 30, 130, 50);
  sort.setLocation(0,220);
  sort_label.setLocation(0,270);
  sort_label.setSize(400,30);
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    Sorting.selectionSort(random);
    Sorting.insertionSort (sort);
    repaint();

}
}
```

Here is my sort class

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


 public class Sorting{

    public static void selectionSort (Comparable[] list)    {

        int min;
        Comparable temp;

        for (int index = 0; index < list.length-1; index++)
        {
            min = index;
            for (int scan = index+1; scan < list.length; scan++)
                if (list[scan].compareTo(list[min]) < 0)
                    min = scan;

            temp = list[min];
            list[min] = list[index];
            list[index] = temp;
        }
    }

    public static void insertionSort (Comparable[] sorter)  {

        for (int index = 1; index < sorter.length; index ++){
            Comparable key = sorter[index];
            int position = index;
            while (position > 0 && key.compareTo(sorter[position-1]) < 0){
                sorter [position] = sorter[position-1];
                position--;
            }

            sorter[position] = key;
        }
    }
```

And then here is my comparable class where I need some help

```
    public class width implements Comparable {

int[] random = new int[20];
int[] sorter = new int[20];



@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {

    int result = 0;

    if(random[1] == sorter[1])
        result = random.length;
    return result;

}
```

Comment: What does it mean for one `width` object to be "less than" (or "greater than") another?

Comment: You have `class width implements Comparable` which means that you want to compare two `width` objects to each other. So if you declare `width w1` and `width w2`. How do you decide whether `w1` comes before `w2`, or vice versa, when you sort them?

Comment: It means they would not be equal. My question is how to get one instance of my array to be able to compare them. I have an array of 20 and i need to compare item 1 vs 2 then 2 vs 3 and so on and so forth every time I click the button I want it to compare the next set

Comment: okay, let's back up. What are the items in your array?

Comment: The items are 20 random numbers generated when the gui is generated. 20 random numbers and I need to compare them

Comment: Both of your sorting algorithms already have the code which compares one item in the array against another item in the array. For example, `key.compareTo(sorter[position-1])` in your `insertionSort()`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19131/discussion-between-code-guru-and-blankwall)

Comment: But how do I create the comparable class to allow this sorting. I feel very lost by this whole setup

Comment: Hey code-guru I got it working but had another quick question maybe you could help with. email is 1blankwall1@gmail.com

Comment: Please post a new question here on Stackoverflow.com so that other's can contribute. Also it will make the information available to anyone who has a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Your comparable class should be whatever you're sorting. In this case you're generating a random array of `int`, so you don't actually need to implement `compareTo`, because `Integer` has already implemented `compareTo`. You would create a new class `width` if the things you were sorting were more complicated than integers.

For example, if your Applet had a bunch of circles it was going to sort by size, you would have something like:

```
public class Circle implements Comparable<Circle> {
    private Point center;
    private double radius;

    public Circle(double radius, Point center) {
        this.center = center;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    // Other drawing functionality

    public int compareTo(Circle c) {
        if (c.radius > radius) return -1;
        if (c.radius == radius) return 0;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

You see? Our object is more complicated, so we need to teach Java how to compare one circle to another, because it doesn't know.

Comment: The Circle class needs to implement `Comparable<Circle>` to get the signature of the `compareTo` method right. But, does this make sense as a way to compare all circles? This seems to be an application-specific requirement, and so I'd use a `Comparator<Circle>` instead.